# Merging of pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have a php page that generates a pdf file by using fpdf. How to merge another pdf  to the same page by using PDFMerge .

```
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF  {
    //some function here
}
```

some code here..

at the end

```
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdfMerge = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', 'all')

    ->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');

$pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'I');
```

when it executes I want to merge `one.pdf` and `filename.pdf`. How to get this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should use a native version of [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) instead the PDFMerger class, because it uses a very old version of FPDI.

```
<?php

require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

class PDF extends FPDI
{
// ...
}

$pdf = new PDF();
// ...
$pageCount = $pdf->setSoruceFile('samplepdfs/one.pdf');
for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    $tplId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplId, null, null, 0, 0, true);
}

$pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'I');
```